# Rewrite htaccess url and remove extension

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite and remove extension

http://www.example.com/pages/cart.php

to

http://www.example.com/cart

My htaccess file is located in the public folder.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. Please confirm if you are hitting link `http://www.example.com/pages/cart.php` in browser?

Comment: Yes, http://www.example.com/pages/cart.php is working without htaccess file. But not with it.

Comment: What error do you get with this code?

Comment: @Tobi, I have posted an answer for this one, please do comment in its comments section once you do test my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess Rules. Make sure you keep your htaccess file along with pages folder(not inside it).

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/pages/(cart)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This solution considers that you are hitting link `http://localhost:80/pages/cart.php` and you want to redirect it to `http://localhost:80/cart/` in browser.

Comment: http://localhost:80/pages/cart -> Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at dev@exutec.de to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: http://localhost:80/ -> Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Comment: @Tobi, please do let me know if you have some other rules also in your htacess apart from these mentioned ones?